# How to add time durations expressed in days-hh:min:ss.nnn format?

Tags: awk, perl

The format of the file is as follows:

```
aaa 1-00:12:43.122
aaa 0-21:14:43.133
bbb 3-11:14:54.433
bbb 2-00:00:10
```

The numbers on the second column are of the format `d-hh:mm:ss.nnn`. The last three decimal digits are absent in some cases. I am trying to figure how to sum them grouped by first column to get the total duration for each user. So, for this example, the result would be:

```
aaa 1-21:27:26.255
bbb 5-11:15:04.433
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `perl`, using a hash and the [DateTime::Format::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/DateTime-Format-Duration-1.04/lib/DateTime/Format/Duration.pm) module, with a regex substitution to regularize the nanoseconds:

```
perl -MDateTime::Format::Duration -ane '
  BEGIN {
    $p = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(pattern => "%e-%H:%M:%S.%N");
  }

  $F[1] =~ s/\d+(\.\d+)?$/sprintf "%02.9f", $&/e;  
  $h{$F[0]} = $h{$F[0]} ? $dt->add_duration($h{$F[0]}) : $dt if $dt = $p->parse_duration($F[1]);

  END { 
    $p = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(pattern => "%e-%H:%M:%S.%3N", normalize => 1);
    for $k (sort keys %h) {printf "%s %s\n", $k, $p->format_duration($h{$k})}
  }
' file
aaa 1-21:27:26.255
bbb 5-11:15:04.433
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this `awk` script:

```
BEGIN {
   FS=" |-|:"
}
{
   data[$1][2]+=$2
   data[$1][3]+=$3
   data[$1][4]+=$4
   data[$1][5]+=$5
}
END {
   for( record in data ) {
      if( data[record][5]>=60 ) {
         data[record][4]+=1
         data[record][5]-=60.0
      }
      if( data[record][4]>=60 ) {
         data[record][3]+=1
         data[record][4]-=60
      }
      if( data[record][3]>=24 ) {
         data[record][2]+=1
         data[record][3]-=24
      }
      printf( "%s %d-%02.0f:%02.0f:%06.3f\n", record, data[record][2], data[record][3], data[record][4], data[record][5] )
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
~/scratch/se/379631$ cat input
aaa 1-00:12:43.122
aaa 0-21:14:43.133
bbb 3-11:14:54.433
bbb 2-00:00:10
~/scratch/se/379631$ gawk -f 379631.awk input
aaa 1-21:27:26.255
bbb 5-11:15:04.433
```

Comment: Thanks! The script works but I am getting wrong results on my file. The hours are going beyond 24, minutes and seconds too go beyond 60 in many cases.

Comment: That's odd because I am deliberately correcting for that.  Though I am only doing one iteration.  Change those `if`s to `whiles` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F'\h+|[-.:]' -lane '
   $h[keys %h]=$F[0] unless $h{$F[0]};
   $h{$F[0]}[$_-1] += $F[$_] for 1..$#F}{for ( @h )
   {
      my @Arefs = map { \$_ } my($days, $hrs, $mins, $secs, $msec) = @{$h{$_}};
      while ( $msec >= 1000 ) { $secs++; $msec -= 1000; }
      while ( $secs >=   60 ) { $mins++; $secs -=   60; }
      while ( $mins >=   60 ) { $hrs++;  $mins -=   60; }
      while ( $hrs  >=   24 ) { $days++; $hrs  -=   24; }
      print $_, sprintf " %d-%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", map $$_, @Arefs;
   }
' text.file

perl -F'\h+|[-.:]' -lane '
   $h[keys %h]=$F[0] unless $h{$F[0]};
   $h{$F[0]}[$_-1] += $F[$_] for 1..$#F}{for ( @h )
   {
      use integer;
      my @A = @{$h{$_}};
      $A[0] += ($A[1] += ($A[2] += ($A[3] += $A[4]/1000)/60)/60)/24;
      $A[4] %= 1000; $A[3] %= 60;$A[2] %= 60; $A[1] %= 24;
      print $_, sprintf " %d-%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", @A;
   }
' text_file
```

---

## Results

```
aaa 1-21:27:26.255
bbb 5-11:15:04.433
```

---

## Explanation

- Field separator is set to take apart the milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days, and first field key.
- The input line is split up and stored in an array `@F` with the elements:
  $F[0] -> key (aaa/bbb/etc.)
  $F[1] -> days, $F[2] -> hours, $F[3] -> minutes, $F[4] -> seconds, $F[5] -> milliseconds.
- Hash keys by their very nature are accessed not in the order they were created, hence we have an array `@h` whose elements are hash `%h` keys in the order they were seen.
- Hash `%h` is constituted this manner:

---

```
%h = (
    aaa => [ days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds ],
    bbb => [                    ...                      ],
    ... 
 );
```